# What Eclipse source code analyzer plugins are there for C/C++ projects?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

The Metrics plugin I installed (http://www.stateofflow.com/UpdateSite) seems to work only on Java projects
Is there an Eclipse source code analyzer plugin for C/C++ projects?

Thanks,
Kenneth

Answer (score 0):

I know about (but I have not tested it) **[cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page)**, which has an [eclipse integration](http://code.google.com/p/cppcheclipse/)

May be Sonar will try to integrate C/C++ source in its tools (see [this message](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg15685.html))